# Change the result in filter string with grep

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

I try `grep -o 'aaa\w*' * >>out` to filter all string start with `aaa...` from multiple file : 1.txt ,2.txt,3.txt ... to out ,and the result is

`1.txt:aaa123
2.txt:aaa222
3.txt:aaaeee
...`

but i just want:

`aaa123
aaa222
aaaeee
...`

How to achieve my goal,
Thanks for any helps .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -h to avoid  printing filenames when using grep on multiple files

Answer (score 1):

then just do

`awk -F'[:]' '{print $2}' file.txt`

considering file.txt to contain your grep result.

file.txt :

```
1.txt:aaa123 
2.txt:aaa222 
3.txt:aaaeee
...
```